# Schrodinger equations on foliated spaces

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics

Schroedinger type equations have been constantly explored in mathematics. I would like to know if is it possible to make sense of physical interpretation in the following setting:

One has a closed manifold $M$ (I mean, it is compact and has no boundary (such as a sphere)) with a group action by a Lie group $G$. Then, state a Schroedinger type equation on this manifold. On could possible ask to: are there $G$-invariant solutions for this equation?

More generally, assume that $M$ is foliated by sub manifolds and analogously pose a Schroedinger equation on it. One could ask: are there solutions that are constant along the leaves?

Are there people studying physics problems on these settings?

I do appreciate comments/references, etc.

Comment: As for the first question, I think the answer is yes. Consider for e.g. the free particle, $V=0$, on a $\mathsf{D}$-sphere. The (time indep.) eq. reduces to the Helmholtz eq., whose solutions are given by linear combinations of hypergeometrics that depend only on the geodesic distance (the polar angle, roughly), which is $SO(\mathsf{D})$  invariant, and the same can also be done for $\mathsf{dS}$ and $\mathsf{AdS}$ (see for ex. https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0110007.pdf near eq. 39). So I guess a similar analysis may hold in the $V\neq0$ ($G$-invariant), but the time dep. problem is more subtle.